# Why RewritePath changes the Browser Url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, httpmodule, cassini

I have an ASP.NET 4 HttpModule (see code below). When the url path starts with "/1.0" I want Cassini/IIS to go to MyService.svc. However, I don't want to show "MyService.svc" to the user (i.e. no update to the url in the browser). I want the user to see "www.something.com/1.0".

I was pretty sure that RewriteUrl isn't supposed to change the browser url, but in my case it does. Any idea why?

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest +=
            delegate
            {
                HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
                const string BasePath = "~/1.0";
                if (path.StartsWith(BasePath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    ctx.RewritePath("~/MyService.svc", "this/is/a/path", string.Empty, false);
                }
            };
    }
```

P.S. I cannot use ASP.NET Routing because of the period/dot in the Url (see [ASP.NET MVC Route IDs with a period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310187/asp-net-mvc-route-ids-with-a-period)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need url routing of ASP.NET, and it's available since .NET 3.5 SP1.

For your case, I think it's easier to "route" instead of rewriting, and it's simpler to use.

Why? MSDN said this:

> In ASP.NET routing, you define URL patterns that contain placeholders
>   for values that are used when you handle URL requests. At run time,
>   the pieces of the URL that follow the application name are parsed into
>   discrete values, based on a URL pattern that you have defined. For
>   example, in the request for
>   http://server/application/Products/show/beverages, the routing parser
>   can pass the values Products, show, and beverages to a handler for the
>   request. In contrast, in a request that is not managed by URL routing,
>   the /Products/show/beverages fragment would be interpreted as the path
>   of a file in the application.
>
> You can also use the URL patterns to programmatically create URLs that
>   correspond to the routes. This enables you to centralize the logic for
>   creating hyperlinks in your ASP.NET application.
>
> ### ASP.NET Routing versus URL Rewriting
>
> ASP.NET routing differs from other URL rewriting schemes. URL
>   rewriting processes incoming requests by actually changing the URL
>   before it sends the request to the Web page. For example, an
>   application that uses URL rewriting might change a URL from
>   /Products/Widgets/ to /Products.aspx?id=4. Also, URL rewriting
>   typically does not have an API for creating URLs that are based on
>   your patterns. In URL rewriting, if you change a URL pattern, you must
>   manually update all hyperlinks that contain the original URL.
>
> With ASP.NET routing, the URL is not changed when an incoming request
>   is handled, because routing can extract values from the URL. When you
>   have to create a URL, you pass parameter values into a method that
>   generates the URL for you. To change the URL pattern, you change it in
>   one location, and all the links that you create in the application
>   that are based on that pattern will automatically use the new pattern.

See [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in MSDN Library.

Comment: I cannot use ASP.NET routing. The period in the Url isn't supported.

Comment: What do you mean period in Url? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Stackoverflow has this valid URL and HAS period in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the same problem as described here:
[ASP.NET RewritePath not working as expected / URL in browser changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853440/asp-net-rewritepath-not-working-as-expected-url-in-browser-changing)

Add the trailing slash to the url:

```
ctx.RewritePath("~/MyService.svc/", "this/is/a/path", string.Empty, false);
```

Also, I'm not sure if WCF engine would preserve PathInfo for you. Possibly you'll have to pass parameters with the URL as QueryString.